# Where are default aliases defined

Tags: bash, alias

I've got a fresh install of CentOS 8 (minimal ISO).  I notice that, despite none being listed in either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, a bunch of aliases are defined by default in bash.  For example,

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
...
```

Many of these aliases I'd like to keep.  However, where can I find/edit the sources of those definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re defined in `/etc/profile` snippets in `/etc/profile.d`; for example, the `egrep` alias comes from `/etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh`.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend editing system files because changes might be lost after an upgrade.

I would recommend instead that you:

1. Either define/undefine aliases using `~/.bashrc` (this will work only for a single user)
2. Or add your own definitions via `/etc/profile.d/my-definitions.sh` file(s).

Comment: alias defined in `~/.bashrc` does not work in shell script :(